# Regex matching?

Tags: python, regex

I have the below regular expression in Python,

```
^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$
```

Since there is a pipe '|', I will split it into 2 regex,

```
^1?$
```

For this, it should validate 1 or *empty* value. Am I correct?

```
^(11+?)\1+$
```

For the above regex, it would validate value of 1111. The first pair of 11 is based on (11+?) and the second pair of 11 is due to \1.

When I attempt to execute it in Python, it returns true only for 1111 but not 11 or empty value. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Hm, prime-vs-composite numbers in unary notation via regexes?

Comment: Yes, trying to write a regex for it. You're good. :)

Comment: @tchrist, nicely spotted! I was kind of stumped after I saw it matched `111111111` (9 `1`'s), and then it occured to me the `\1+` was matching 3 times 3 `1`'s. :)

Comment: Ted, you might want to edit your post to include what you're actually trying to match: we're not all as smart as tchrist! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Ted wrote:***
>
> For this, it should validate 1 or empty value. Am I correct?

Yes, that is correct.

> ***Ted wrote:***
>
> When I attempt to execute it in Python, it returns true only for 1111 but not 11 or empty value. Am I wrong somewhere?

The empty string *does* get matched. The following snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

for n in xrange(0, 51):
  ones = '1' * n
  matches = re.match(r'^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$', ones)
  if matches:
    div1 = n if matches.group(1) is None else len(matches.group(1))
    div2 = 0 if div1 is 0 else len(ones)/div1
    print "[{0:2}]:{1:2} * {2:2} = '{3}'".format(n, div1, div2, ones)
```

will print:

```
[ 0]: 0 *  0 = ''
[ 1]: 1 *  1 = '1'
[ 4]: 2 *  2 = '1111'
[ 6]: 2 *  3 = '111111'
[ 8]: 2 *  4 = '11111111'
[ 9]: 3 *  3 = '111111111'
[10]: 2 *  5 = '1111111111'
[12]: 2 *  6 = '111111111111'
[14]: 2 *  7 = '11111111111111'
[15]: 3 *  5 = '111111111111111'
[16]: 2 *  8 = '1111111111111111'
[18]: 2 *  9 = '111111111111111111'
[20]: 2 * 10 = '11111111111111111111'
[21]: 3 *  7 = '111111111111111111111'
[22]: 2 * 11 = '1111111111111111111111'
[24]: 2 * 12 = '111111111111111111111111'
[25]: 5 *  5 = '1111111111111111111111111'
[26]: 2 * 13 = '11111111111111111111111111'
[27]: 3 *  9 = '111111111111111111111111111'
[28]: 2 * 14 = '1111111111111111111111111111'
[30]: 2 * 15 = '111111111111111111111111111111'
[32]: 2 * 16 = '11111111111111111111111111111111'
[33]: 3 * 11 = '111111111111111111111111111111111'
[34]: 2 * 17 = '1111111111111111111111111111111111'
[35]: 5 *  7 = '11111111111111111111111111111111111'
[36]: 2 * 18 = '111111111111111111111111111111111111'
[38]: 2 * 19 = '11111111111111111111111111111111111111'
[39]: 3 * 13 = '111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
[40]: 2 * 20 = '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
[42]: 2 * 21 = '111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
[44]: 2 * 22 = '11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
[45]: 3 * 15 = '111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
[46]: 2 * 23 = '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
[48]: 2 * 24 = '111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
[49]: 7 *  7 = '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
[50]: 2 * 25 = '11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
```

And the input `11` is not matched because `11` is matched in group 1 (`(11+?)`), which should then be repeated at least once (`\1+`), which is not the case (it  is not repeated).

Comment: For the first set of regex, ^1?$, empty value is matched, but why isn't 1 or 11 matched? Since 1 fits the matching in ^1 and 11 fits the matching in 1?.

Comment: @Ted, the empty string and `"1"` _are_ matched. See my (slightly) edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! I was mistaken about the `(^1?$)`. I thought it means 1 or 11 due to the `?` metacharacter (zero or one).

Comment: @Ted, ah I see. Then you probably meant: `^11?$|^(11+?)\1+$`

Comment: It is not really necessary to have the complex regex to match a lines on 1's or a blank. Why not `r'^(1?)|(1+)$`?

Comment: @carrot-top, not sure if that was meant as a joke or not. The OP is _not_ simply trying tto match `'1'`'s. See the comment tchrist made beneath the original question. Besides, your suggestion `^(1?)|(1+)$` (where you probably meant `^(1?)$|^(1+)$`) could simply be written as: `^1*$`

Comment: @Bart Kiers: I didn't mean it as a joke; I just didn't get it at first. The pattern goes from `11` to `111` on every length of "1" that that is a multiple of 3. It would be more clear to the uninitiated to add `print re.match(r'^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$',ones).groups()` to the `if` in your loop...

Comment: @carrot-top, well, I'm not answering the uninitiated, but the one asking the question :). And it's not just printing multiples of 2 and 3, also 21 ( 3*7) and 25 (5*5) will also be printed if you increase the range.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `+` after the `\1` meaning a greedy 1 or more.

Are you trying to match `1` between 1 and 4 times?

Use:

```
r'^(1+){1,4}$'
```

The easiest is to use one of the great regex tools out there. Here is [my favorite.](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2upkb) With the same site, you can see why [your regex does not work](http://regexr.com?2upke).

Here is a site that [explains regex's](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%281%2b%29%7B1,4%7D%24).

Comment: With or without the `+` after `\1`, the input `"11"` still is not matched, and the empty string _will_ be matched. In other words: the `+` is as far as I understand not the problem. Unless I am misinterpreting things...

Comment: @Bart Kiers: Well it is a little unclear what the OP is trying to do ;-) I interpreted it that he wanted to split a regex and have the second match a line with 1, 11, 111, or 1111. His regex only matches 1111 out of that set.

Comment: Err, no, `"1"` is also matched. I agree with you that it's a bit unclear though! :)

Comment: Bart Kiers: The regex of `'^(11+?)\1+$'` most assuredly does not match `"1"`. There is the literal `1` followed by 1 or more literal `1` characters in a capture group. So `11` followed by any number of additional `1`'s. If he replaced both `+` with `*` to make the second `1` optional and the capture group optional, THEN it would match `1`...

Comment: I didn't say `"1"` is matched by `'^(11+?)\1+$'`. Please see the original pattern in the OP: `^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$`, which _does_ match `"1"` (the part: `^1?$`, to be precise). See my answer: is contains a demo you can run.

Comment: Bart Kiers: O, I didn't know that you meant with the alteration `|` I thought you meant just the second half, since the OP stated he was separating the two regexes. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second expression to match '11', '1111', '111111', etc.  Use:

```
^(1+)\1$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need more parenthesis to define what the `|` refers to. I would write the regex like this:

```
/^(1?|^(11+?)\2+)$/
```

note there is only one start and end used

Comment: Nope, that matches exactly the same as `^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$`